# Can't figure out where does the stored procedure save the data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Not so strong at Transact-SQL and stored procedures. I want to know where does that procedure save the data ?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsurerCascoConditionsSave]
     @InsurerID int
    ,@Data xml
AS
BEGIN

    declare @DocHandle int
    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @DocHandle OUTPUT, @Data

    MERGE InsurerCascoConditions AS target
    USING (SELECT InsurerConditionID, @InsurerID, CascoConditionID, Value
            FROM OPENXML (@DocHandle, '/DocumentElement/Table1', 2)
            WITH (InsurerConditionID int, CascoConditionID int, Value nvarchar(max)))
        AS source (InsurerConditionID, InsurerID, CascoConditionID, Value)
    ON (target.ID = isnull(source.InsurerConditionID, 0))
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET Value = source.Value
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
        INSERT (InsurerID, CascoConditionID, Value)
        VALUES (source.InsurerID, source.CascoConditionID, source.Value);

    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @DocHandle
END
```

Comment: MERGE InsurerCascoConditions AS **target**

Answer (score 1):

To the `InsurerCascoConditions` table.

It's done by `MERGE` statement, you can read about it on [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx). Generally it makes `INSERT` or `UPDATE` or `DELETE` depending on condition. It can be easliy read from syntax.

Comment: ok... But can there be some reason why you cant select data form table (it returns 0 row.. But i know that there has to be something..)

Answer (score 1):

As @psur said, InsurerCascoConditions is the table that will be modified. MERGE allows you to do INSERT/UPDATE/DELETEs as part of a single statement instead of doing 3 separate statements.

Breaking down your statement....

`MERGE InsurerCascoConditions AS target` -- this the target table for this operation

`USING` ..... -- this is the source from where data is originating

`ON` .... -- defines how the source data relates to the target data (e.g. matches on an ID)

`WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE`.... -- if a record in the SOURCE matches a record in the TARGET based on the above `ON` condition, this defines which fields in the matched target record, to update with which fields from the matched source record

`WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT`.... -- if a record in the SOURCE does NOT match a record in the TARGET based on the above `ON` condition, this inserts a new row into the target table